# Paste images from clipboard to word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, clipboard

I want to paste images, and when I say images, I mean the clipboard will be packed with over 18images, that we need to paste as separate objects. I tried
 `Selection.Paste` but it does work only for the last used pic. Can anyone pl help.

The images or objects are basically some random text and images from web browsers. But while pasting on the document, the order needs to be maintained or controlled.

Comment: I disagree with your assumption that "the clipboard will be packed with over 18images". That is not possible.

Comment: I'm sorry for not framing the question correctly, a clip board, at a time, can hold 24 objects, as per my observation. My job is to grab a few of those objects and paste on a word document...

Answer (score 1):

You can have only one image at the time in your clipboard. 
So if you have 18 items, you need to go back and forth.

I am aware that Microsoft word supports this clipboard in which you can hold multiple items, however that will only work when you want to paste it into some other Microsoft Office (Excel / Outlook / etc) product (Microsoft Paint will most likely NOT work)

Comment: I actually need to paste the images into the word document... and the images or objects are, say, randomly picked from web pages

Comment: If you use to clipboard FROM an office product TO another office product (e.g. Word to Excel or Word to Word) you can use the clipboard with the 24 items. In any other case, the system clipboard will be used, which can hold only 1 item. For details about the office clipboard, please read  [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/copy-and-paste-multiple-items-by-using-the-office-clipboard-HA010163602.aspx)

Comment: as to what I remember, these images/objects, are displayed under the office clip board when I copy them. Could you pl share some code that may help me understand the possibilities of my aim... `Select.Paste` is not working out as desired